# Como chamar ler as respostas HTTP

Tags: angular

Bom gostaria de trazer algumas mensagens de erro no JSON para essa classe abaixo e não sei como fazer isso, minha conexão com o Banco de Dados está OK e voltando o JSON certinho, eu gostaria de ler os Response que estou enviando de volta, mas não sei como fazer isso, pesquisei na internet e não achei, gostaria por exemplo de fazer o seguinte por exemplo se vir um erro Http 404 eu faço alguma coisa, erro 500 outra coisa e sucesso outra coisa, na verdade Mostrar um Modal na tela mostrando essas mensagens que viria no Response, alguém tem uma ideia de fazer isso aqui no service? no retorno do JSON.

Um exemplo como eu queria:

```
saveUsuario(usuario: Usuario): Observable<Usuario> {
    if (http code 404 ) {
        chama modal
    } else if (http code 500) {
        chama modal
    }
}
```

Minha Classe - Service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Usuario } from "./usuario";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class UsuarioService {

  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/usuario';

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  saveUsuario(usuario: Usuario): Observable<Usuario> {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, usuario)
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }

  deleteUsuarioById(codigoUsuario: number): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.delete(this.apiUrl + '/' + codigoUsuario)
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }

  updateUsuario(usuario: Usuario): Observable<Usuario> {
    return this.http.put(this.apiUrl, usuario)
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }

  findById(codigoUsuario: number): Observable<Usuario> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/' + codigoUsuario)
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Error'));
  }

  findAll(): Observable<Usuario[]>  {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }

  login(loginUsuario: string, senhaUsuario: string): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/login/' + loginUsuario + '/senha/' + senhaUsuario)
      .map((res: Response) => {
        if (res) {
          if (res.status === 201) {
            return [{ status: res.status, json: res }]
          } else if (res.status === 200) {
            return [{ status: res.status, json: res }]
          }
        }
        }).catch((error: any) => {
          if (error.status === 500) {
            return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
          }
          else if (error.status === 400) {
            return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
          }
          else if (error.status === 409) {
            return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
          }
          else if (error.status === 406) {
            return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
          }});
  }

}
```

Minha Classe - Component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { UsuarioService } from "../usuario.service";
import { Usuario } from "../usuario";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-usuario-login',
  templateUrl: './usuario-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./usuario-login.component.css'],
    providers: [UsuarioService]
})
export class UsuarioLoginComponent implements OnInit {

    private usuarioForm : FormGroup;

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
                private router: Router,
                private usuarioService: UsuarioService,
                private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
                private toastr: ToastrService) {

    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.usuarioForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      loginUsuario: ['', Validators.required ],
      senhaUsuario: ['', Validators.required ]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  error: string;
  data: any;

  onSubmit(loginUsuario, senhaUsuario) {
    this.usuarioService.login(loginUsuario, senhaUsuario)
       .subscribe(
         data => this.data = data,
         err  => this.error = <any>err.message);
  }

}
```

Modelo JSON - Retorno:

```
{
    "code": 4,
    "message": "Sucesso"
}
```

Consegui chegar no meu Componenent com o JSON assim:

Meu Service:

```js
  login(loginUsuario: string, senhaUsuario: string): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/login/' + loginUsuario + '/senha/' + senhaUsuario)
      .map((res: Response) => {
        if (res) {
          if (res.status === 201) {
            return [{ json: res._body }]
          } else if (res.status === 200) {
            return [{ json: res._body }]
          }
        }
        }).catch((error: any) => {
          if (error.status === 500) {
            return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
          }
          else if (error.status === 400) {
            return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
          }
          else if (error.status === 409) {
            return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
          }
          else if (error.status === 406) {
            return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
          }});
  }
```

Meu Component:

```js
  onSubmit(loginUsuario, senhaUsuario) {

    this.usuarioService.login(loginUsuario, senhaUsuario).subscribe(
       data => {
         console.log(data);
       },
       error => {
         console.error("Error saving food!");
         return Observable.throw(error);
       }
    );
```

Como pegar dentro do DATA agora e pegar esse Entity que está dentro do DATA.

Comment: A dúvida é como saber qual código http de erro o seu backend retornou?

Comment: a dúvida é como pegar aqui no Angular esses retornos por exemplo quando o erro for 404, 500 ou outro. Quero pegar o Response aqui no Angular e tratar esses erros pra enviar mensagens na Tela.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer algo assim:

```js
saveUsuario(usuario: Usuario): Observable<Usuario> {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, usuario)
        .catch((error: any) => {
            return Observable.throw(error);
        });
}
```

Utilizando [`Observable.throw`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-throw) você emite nenhum item para o *Observer* e imediatemente emite uma notificação de erro. Tal notificação pode ser manipulada no *callback* de erro.

Para tratar o erro dentro do seu componente:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'meu-app',
    template: `
        <div>Código: {{ erro.code }}</div>
        <div>Mensagem: {{ erro.message }}</div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    erro: any;
    data: any;

    constructor(private usuarioadminservice: UsuarioAdminService ) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.usuarioadminservice.saveUsuario(null)
            .subscribe(
                data => this.data = data,
                err  => this.erro = <any>err
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: isso amigo, é isso mesmo que eu queria, mas como eu pego essa informação depois aonde ele está chamando no Component do Angular? porque ele está retornando um Observable.

Comment: @EdersonCoelho no caso você quer passar o código do erro para o componente?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo

Comment: @EdersonCoelho editei a resposta.

Comment: Estou quase no caminho, incluí aqui exatamente o que eu quero fazer, pra você entender o JSON que eu coloquei, é exatamente o que vai voltar nesse caso preciso pegar o Código e a Mensagem que está dentro do Entity dentro do JSON passar pro Component e pegar essa Mensagem e exibir na tela.

Comment: Fiz mais algumas atualizações no Código Fonte, estou quase conseguindo fazer o que eu queria fazer, se der pra me ajudar ou tiver alguma maneira melhor, agradeço. Eu preciso saber agora como eu pego o Entity dentro da váriavel DATA dentro do Component que está voltando certinho agora, mais se tiver alguma maneira melhor estou a disposição a ver.

Comment: @EdersonCoelho `data.context.entity.code` e `data.context.entity.message`. Se o mesmo formato de JSON for retornado quando houver um erro no backend, segue a mesma lógica: `err.context.entity.code` e `err.context.entity.message`.

Comment: core.js:1427 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'entity' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (usuario-login.component.ts:46)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:240)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:187)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:128)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:128)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1591)

Comment: Não está conseguindo ler a propriedade entity.

Comment: Estou descobrindo amigo na verdade eu tenho que pegar como data[0].entity sempre chega como um Array no Response, só que agora como eu acesso o code e a message que está dentro do entity?

Comment: Até aqui funciona data[0].entity, mas data[0].entity.code e data[0].message não funciona.

Comment: @EdersonCoelho pode imprimir no console o conteúdo de `data` e colar aqui para que possamos analisar?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71775/discussion-between-mercador-and-ederson-coelho).